# When to create a new SessionFactory?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my app I've been passing my `SessionFatory` in my method parameters when I need to access my database within those methods. It's instantiated in my Controller using:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

And when I need to access my database I use lines like this:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save() 
// or
List products = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS").list();
```

Should I be creating new sessionFactories to get my current session or should is it okay to pass it as a parameter?

edit [added for clarity]:

From HomeController.java:

@Controller
public class HomeController {

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
//Correlations Insert Handler
//DOCUMENT CREATE
@RequestMapping(value="/documents", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody String insertDocument(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){       

    DocumentControl documentControl = new DocumentControl();
    documentControl.insertDocument(request, response, sessionFactory);
    return "went through just find";

}
//DOCUMENT READ
@RequestMapping(value="/documents", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Documents> getAllDocuments(){
    //List documents = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Documents").list();         
    DocumentControl documentControl = new DocumentControl();
    List documents = documentControl.getAllDocuments(sessionFactory);
    return documents;
}
```

From DocumentControl.java:

```
public class DocumentControl {

        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DocumentControl.class.getName());
        public DocumentControl(){};
        //CREATE
        public void insertDocument(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    Documents document = new Documents(request)
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(document);  
        }           

        //READ
        public List<DocumentReturn> getAllDocuments(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
            List documents = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Documents").list();

            return documents;
        }



        private boolean ifProductExists (String productCode, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            boolean exists = false;

            List<Products> productList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Products.class).add( Restrictions.eq("productCode", productCode)).list();

            if ( !productList.isEmpty()  && productList.size() > 0 ) {
                exists = true;
            }

            return exists;
        }

        private boolean ifStandardExists (String standardCode, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            boolean exists = false;

            List<Standards> standardList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Standards.class).add( Restrictions.eq("standardCode", standardCode)).list();

            if ( !standardList.isEmpty()  && standardList.size() > 0 ) {
                exists = true;
            }

            return exists;
        }
    }
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>      
        <mapping class="***.*****.********.model.Documents"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

persistence-context.xml:

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />     
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>             
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>              
                <prop key=" hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>     

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <

property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I don't see you creating new `SessionFactory` objects.

Comment: Why do you need 2 `SessionFactory` instances? Remember, `SessionFactory` instances are costly resource. You should only create an extra object when you really need it, for example, when you want to connect to multiple databases in a single application.

Answer (score 0):

SessionFactory is a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Therefore, you should get it from the ApplicationContext (i.e. using the `@Autowired` annotation). Passing it as a parameter will only complicate your API.

Comment: This topic has not much to do with a `Singleton Pattern`, focus on main issue.

Comment: Yes it does. Do you think it's ok to pass a Singleton as a parameter?

Comment: I think it is kind off topic. OP is autowiring it, so everyhing is just fine as for that aspect.

Comment: @Antoniossss, maybe you didn't read the question: "Should I be creating new sessionFactories to get my current session or should is it okay to pass it as a parameter?"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should leave creation of `SessionFactory` to the framework you are using and inject it as a resource just as you are doing by now. Besides you are not creating it in your code at all. Good practice is to create separate session for every chunk of data manipulation, if it is not done by a framework ofc. Session should be your main unit of work.

Comment: So if I need to access the database in another class I would just create a new Session. Then session.getCurrentSession() ?

Comment: When you invoke the getCurrentSession() method, you're not creating a session.

Comment: @Andres You are right, but only partially as it depends on implementation (session can be bind to thread and be created to request) and context  that it is used for.

Comment: @Jonathan. Yes that is correct. I bet on that you have session management enabled (probably bind to view or even better - to single request). If it is, you will not have even to close it nor flush. But that is pure cunfiguration issue.

Comment: However, saying that "good practice is to create a separate session for every chunk of data manipulation" is wrong on any context.

Comment: @Andres Could you elaborate on that and explain yourself why, or you will just stay with it that I am wrong with no explanation?

Comment: The usual patterns are "session per thread" or "session per conversation", not "session per chunk of data manipulation".

Comment: Yes, you are right - I would be carefull with session per conversations as it can simply drain connection DB connection pool preventing clients accessing DB till other conversations are done. As for session per thread - you never close your sessions ? OFC. I can only say that it depends on thread life time. 
As session occupies connection from pool, it should be aquired when needed and released as soon as possible.

Comment: No. Since I use Spring+Hibernate+JPA, I never close my sessions explicitly. Do you?

Comment: Thanks guys for you help, I really appreciate the discussion.